# Node-Red Feedparse not working on some RSS feeds

Tags: rss, node-red

Cannot get [Node-Red Feedparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-node-feedparser) Feed parse to work on these URLs

https://tradingeconomics.com/rss/news.aspx?i=gasoline+prices

https://tradingeconomics.com/rss/news.aspx?i=government+bond+10y

I am sure I am missing something. Please can you help.

Comment: Is there anything reported in the debug sidebar or the logs?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like tradingeconomics is being VERY strict about who it will reply to.

The Node-RED feedparser node is not setting a User-Agent string so they are not returning the content of the feed.

It looks like the Node-RED node used to set one at some point because it is commented out in the src, so the quick fix would be to uncomment line 22 in the 32-feedparser.js file and restart Node-RED.

You should probably raise an issue against the [node-red-nodes](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes) project on github to find out why that line was removed and if it can be returned.

Comment: Unfortunately the commenting out of that line pre-dates the file being put into git... so the reasons may be lost to the mists of time. Can certainly investigate exposing some of these as options.... once an issue has been raised.